# How do I match an entire line from a text file and break it into variable using Python and RegEx?

Tags: python, regex

Hello I am having the following issue with RegEx and Python.

I am trying to take the following from a text file and break it into variables (The text file contains 28k+ lines, not just the below text):

```
VOLUME 26 4—PART 23
```

The only two constant values in the line are VOLUME and PART the numbers alternate.

Ideally, the above string would get matched from a text file and parsed into 3 variables.

```
volume = 26
epitome = 4
part = 23
```

I have tried:

```
^.*VOLUME.*$
```

Unfortunately, the above RegEx matches the entire file after the word volume is found. I just need the one line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `d = {k:int(v) for k,v in zip(['volume','epitome','part'],re.findall('\d+',txt))}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\d` regex pattern to match digits and the `\D` pattern to match characters that aren't digits. You also need to include parenthesis around the groups that you want to capture so that `match` or `findall` will return the groups.

```
import re
s = "VOLUME 26 4—PART 23"
pattern = re.compile('VOLUME (\d+) (\d+)—PART (\d+)')
print(pattern.findall(s))
```

If you aren't certain that the VOLUME and PART will always be the same, you can use this, more general, pattern instead:

```
pattern = re.compile('\D+(\d+) (\d+)\D+(\d+)')
```

Running either pattern prints:

```
[('26', '4', '23')]
```

To extract the results to your variables, replace the `print()` line with:

```
result = pattern.findall(s)[0]
volume, epitome, part = (int(i) for i in result)
```

### Match with optional epitome

You can make the middle item (epitome) optional by wrapping it in a non-capturing group `(?:...)`. Follow this with a `?` to tell it to match 0 or 1 occurrences and it will work for lines with or without the epitome. If the epitome is missing, the 2nd element in the `result` tuple will be an empty string `''`.

Here is the working example:

```
import re
sl = ["VOLUME 26 4—PART 23", "VOLUME 16 4-PART 7", "VOLUME 12-PART 38"]
pattern = re.compile('\D+(\d+)(?: (\d+))?\D+(\d+)')
for s in sl:
    result = pattern.findall(s)[0]
    volume, epitome, part = (int(i) if i else i for i in result)
    print('"{}": v {}, e {}, p {}'.format(s, volume, epitome, part))
```

Running this produces:

```
"VOLUME 26 4—PART 23": v 26, e 4, p 23
"VOLUME 16 4-PART 7": v 16, e 4, p 7
"VOLUME 12-PART 38": v 12, e , p 38
```

Comment: Works like a charm. However, if the volume is let's say 3 digits I am thinking this will not work? Such as VOLUME 123 5-PART 126

Comment: @CodeHard It will still work. The `\d+` matches one or more number characters. You can test this at: https://regex101.com/r/UtpXZi/1

Comment: is there anyway to be a bit lose on the middle integer as some files have: VOLUME 12-PART 38 and others have VOLUME 16 4-PART 7. Despite, you have answered the original question and I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: @CodeHard - I've updated my answer with a regex that handles cases where the epitome is missing. I've also updated the code at Regex101 so you can see how this work.

Comment: I know I am not supposed to thank you in the comments. However, I have learned so much from you. Thank you for sharing your time.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7

```
import re
s = "sdfdsjflsfVOLUME 26 4—PART 23sfldfls = VOLUME 26 4—PART 23sjjkfj"
regex = r"VOLUME.\d+.\d+.[^PART]+PART.\d+"
all_patterns = re.findall(regex, s)
for pattern in all_patterns:
    volume, epitome, part = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', pattern))
    print(volume, epitome, part)
```

In python3

```
import re
s = "sdfdsjflsfVOLUME 26 4—PART 23sfldfls = VOLUME 26 4—PART 23sjjkfj"
regex = re.compile("VOLUME.\d+.\d+—PART.\d+")
all_patterns = regex.findall(s)
for pattern in all_patterns:
    r = re.compile("\d+")
    volume, epitome, part = map(int, r.findall(pattern))
    print(volume, epitome, part)
```

Comment: Does not return any match. Variables are empty.

Comment: Still not working. Not returning any matches, variables are empty.

Comment: @CodeHard copy above code and run it. it will work. or could you update question with your code ?

Comment: I used your code exactly and Process finished with exit code 0 is the only status printed to the terminal.

Comment: Windows 10 Python 3.6.1, I am sorry, it did not work for me. I do appreciate your time.

Comment: @CodeHard I've updated my code to python3 check it now